# How to upload file to box from ios app?

Tags: ios, file-upload, box

I got the following from box developers site.

```
curl https://upload.box.com/api/2.0/files/content \
-H "Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN" \
-F filename=@FILE_NAME \
-F parent_id=PARENT_FOLDER_ID
```

- F indicates what ? how to make a request url ?

Answer (score 0):

-F: emulate a filled-in form in which a user has pressed the submit button. This causes curl to POST data using the Content-Type multipart/form-data according to RFC 2388 standard. -F accepts parameters like -F "name=contents" for contents to be read from a file, use <@filename> as contents. When specifying a file, you can also specify the file content type by appending ';type='
  to the file name.

Emulate a fill-in form with -F. Let's say you fill in three fields in a
  form. One field is a file name which to post, one field is your name and one
  field is a file description. We want to post the file we have written named
  "cooltext.txt".

**CUrl example (sending couple fields and file):**

```
    curl -F "file=@cooltext.txt" -F "yourname=Daniel" \ 
         -F "filedescription=Cool text file with cool text inside" \ 
         http://www.post.com/postit.cgi
```

**Objective-c example (sending one form value):**

```
/*
 * Create Mutable URL request and get method to Post with content type as a form
 */
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.exmaple.com/post"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];

/*
 * build http body
 */
NSData *data = [@"firstname" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[request setHTTPBody:data];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%u", data.length] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

/*
 * Make request and return result
 */
NSError *error;
NSHTTPURLResponse *response;
NSData *result = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

if (error) {
    NSLog(@"request error: %@", error);

    return;
}

NSString *formattedResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:result encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"result: %@ http headers: %@", formattedResult, response.allHeaderFields);
```

References:
[CUrl man pages](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html)
[RFC 2388 standard](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2388.txt)

Comment: you mean in objective-c?

Answer (score 0):

Here i got the solution .

```
   NSString * accessToken =  [[arrUseraccounts objectAtIndex:[DropboxDownloadFileViewControlller getSharedInstance].index] objectForKey:@"acces_token"];
    NSString * filename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"@%@",[[filePathsArray objectAtIndex:k]objectForKey:@"PdfName"]];
    NSString * boxParentId = [DetailViewController  getSharedInstance].folderPath;

    NSString *str =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://upload.box.com/api/2.0/files/content?access_token=%@&filename=%@&parent_id=%@",accessToken,filename,boxParentId];

    ASIFormDataRequest *postParams = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:str]];
    postParams.delegate = self ;
    postParams.userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"upload" forKey:@"id"];
// set the path of the file where it is saved (local Path)
    [postParams setFile:[[filePathsArray objectAtIndex:k]objectForKey:@"PdfPath"] forKey:@"filename"];

    [postParams startAsynchronous];
```

Answer (score 0):

Uploading file to box is very easy. Please find code below.

```
- (void)performSampleUpload:(id)sender
{
    BoxFileBlock fileBlock = ^(BoxFile *file)
    {
        [self fetchFolderItemsWithFolderID:self.folderID name:self.navigationController.title];

        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"File Upload Successful" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"File has id: %@", file.modelID] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alertView show];
        });
    };

    BoxAPIJSONFailureBlock failureBlock = ^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, NSDictionary *JSONDictionary)
    {
        BOXLog(@"status code: %i", response.statusCode);
        BOXLog(@"upload response JSON: %@", JSONDictionary);
    };

    BoxFilesRequestBuilder *builder = [[BoxFilesRequestBuilder alloc] init];
    builder.name = @"Logo_Box_Blue_Whitebg_480x480.jpg";
    builder.parentID = self.folderID;

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Logo_Box_Blue_Whitebg_480x480.jpg" ofType:nil];
    NSInputStream *inputStream = [NSInputStream inputStreamWithFileAtPath:path];
    NSDictionary *fileAttributes = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:path error:nil];
    long long contentLength = [[fileAttributes objectForKey:NSFileSize] longLongValue];

    [[BoxSDK sharedSDK].filesManager uploadFileWithInputStream:inputStream contentLength:contentLength MIMEType:nil requestBuilder:builder success:fileBlock failure:failureBlock progress:nil];
}
```

Enjoy coding.. Cheers.